# Using Regex to search for a string unless it finds another string first

Tags: python, regex

Hello I'm trying to use regex to search through a markdown file for a date and only get a match if it finds an instance of a specific string before it finds another date.

This is what I have right now and it definitely doesn't work.
`(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})(string)?(^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}))`

So in this instance It would throw a match since the string is before the next date:

```
01/20/20

string

01/21/20
```

Here it shouldn't match since the string is after the next date:

```
01/20/20

this isn't the phrase you're looking for

01/21/20

string
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?:(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).)*string.*?\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}`  https://regex101.com/r/FREPRt/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match a date like pattern. Then use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach `(?:(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).)*` to match `string` without matching another date first.

If you have matched the `string`, use a non greedy dot `.*?` to match the first occurrence of the next date.

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?:(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).)*string.*?\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ak2Dy5/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tEboOS)

For example (using `re.DOTALL` to make the dot match a newline)

```
import re

regex = r"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?:(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).)*string(?:(?!string|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).)*\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}"

test_str = """01/20/20\n\n"
    "string\n\n"
    "01/21/20\n\n"
    "01/20/20\n\n"
    "this isn't the phrase you're looking for\n\n"
    "01/21/20\n\n"
    "string"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

Output

```
['01/20/20\n\n"\n\t"string\n\n"\n\t"01/21/20']
```

---

If the `string` can not occur 2 times between the date, you might use

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?:(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}|string).)*string(?:(?!string|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}).)*\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Npr7ff/1)

Note that if you don't want the string and the dates to be part of a larger word, you could add word boundaries `\b`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is just the answer for my comment, which looks like your answer afterwards :) But you will get my vote anyway

Comment: @The Fourth Bird That does match correctly but two things. How do I get it to return all instances of this match? and two How do I get it to return only the initial date after it has confirmed that it is a match.

Comment: @CaptainPo-Po Fourth's answer already matches all instances of the match +1.  For the second requirement, you only need to change the capture group in the call to `re.findall`.

Comment: @CaptainPo-Po You could indeed use a capturing group for the first date https://regex101.com/r/khGQ8G/1 Using re.findall will return only the capturing group. If you want the match and the groups, you could use re.finditer. This is an example of the auto generated code by regex101 https://ideone.com/2M19fp

Comment: Okay yeah I see that now. I've been tinkering and I've run into an error when running this: `TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'` i've replaced the phrase "string" with the actual string I need, is one of those a command of some sort?

Comment: @CaptainPo-Po [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) has this function definition `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)` so the second parameter is the actual string.

Comment: Will this method catch a date if it exists in a larger string?

Comment: Okay, That's odd then. I'm not getting any matches even though there should be at least one

Answer (score 1):

One approach here would be to use a tempered dot to ensure that the regex engine does not cross over the ending date while trying to find the string after the starting date.  For example:

```
inp = """01/20/20

string                  # <-- this is matched

01/21/20

01/20/20

01/21/20

string"""               # <-- this is not matched

matches = re.findall(r'01/20/20(?:(?!\b01/21/20\b).)*?(\bstring\b).*?\b01/21/20\b', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints `string` only once, that match being the first occurrence, which legitimately sits in between the starting and ending dates.